# ASP.net MVC in RDLC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a RDLC report and I am displaying it on the Report Viewer Control in my front end application. I get the report perfectly and theres no problem in it.

But the problem arises when i generate the PDF then showing this PDF one page is generated given data And another page is blank...pls help me for removing this blank page..

Comment: I dont think it's very obvious what you are having problems with, can you provide us with the sample code or link.

Answer (score 0):

Check the report width, in your report designer you may have more width then the A4, and don't forget the margin effect too.